# How can I prove $\exists k \in \Bbb N, \forall n \in \Bbb N, n \ge 4 \to {n \choose k} \gt n$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I think this works if you let $k=n/2$ when $n$ is even and $k=n/2+1/2$ if $n$ is odd, but I am unsure how to prove that this works or if what I claimed is even true.

Could someone possibly get me started or point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Your suggestion will not work; note that you are asked to prove that "there is a $k$ such that for all $n$ ..." and not "for every $n$ there is a $k$ such that ...". That is, your choice of $k$ cannot depend on $n$. Hint: try some small values of $k$. Does 0 work? Does 1 work? Does 2 work?

Comment: Oh - I was fundamentally misunderstanding the question. Thanks for clarifying it for me. I see now that 2 works because you're then left with $n(n-1)/2$ and it's easy to prove that value is always greater than $n$.

Answer (score 1):

For $k=2$, we have \begin{align}
\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}
\end{align}
Then using the Gauss identity \begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=\frac{(n-1)(n-1+1)}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2},
\end{equation*}
we get\begin{align}
\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k=(n-1)+1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}k=n+\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}k.
\end{align}Since $\sum_{k=2}^{n-2}k>0$ for $n>4$, we obtain the desired inequality.

Answer (score 0):

$k=2$. Proof: we need to prove that $n(n-1)/2 > n$ for all $n \geq 4$.
In other words, that $n^2-3n>0$. This parabola has $2$ roots: $n=0$ and $n=3$.
Between the roots it assumes negative values, and outside it assumes positive values.
In particular, for $n \geq 4$ it is positive.

Answer (score 0):

$k=2$ works, since in a set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ with $n\geq4$, we can choose at least $n+1$ pairs, namely: $$\underbrace{(1,2),(1,3),\ldots,(1,n)}_{n-1\text{ pairs}},(2,3),(2,4).$$